# children of HTML element different background on line-break

Tags: html, css, background, line-breaks

Why isn't all the children's background color the same as the parent's one HTML CSS if there is a line break separating the two,
for example if my font-size is 20:

```html
<div style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);font-size: 20px;"><span style="text-align:left; color: blue;">Roberto#3<span style="float:right;">18:21</span></span></div>
```

it works perfectly, but if my font size is 130

```html
<div style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);font-size: 130px;"><span style="text-align:left; color: blue;">Roberto#3<span style="float:right;">18:21</span></span></div>
```

and how to solve that simply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content width is greater than the element containing it, and it is floated, it will "overflow" outside of its container.
Then we can add overflow: auto; to the containing element to fix this problem :

```html
<div style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);font-size: 130px; overflow: auto;"> 
  <span style="text-align:left; color: blue;">Roberto#3<span 
  style="float:right;">18:21</span></span></div>
```